# Detect Click Event On ItemDecoration In RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

I'm using itemdecorations to draw header in my recyclerview.

Is there a way to detect click event on itemdecorations in recyclerview.

P.S: I don't want to make a multiview type adapter.